# Is there a bittorrent client which has an embedded tracker?

Tags: bittorrent

Bittorrent trackers are a bit of a mystery to me, but I do recall (a couple of years ago) that I managed to set up a MS Window bittorrent client (uTorrent) to make a private .torrent and then manage it (privately)...

I'd like to do the same with a Linux/Ubuntu program...  and I'd prefer to stay with Upuntu repository options.

I want to **be the tracker**.. (not just make a "private" .torrent)

Update: in 'Deluge' terminology, it is called an **embedded tracker** (but Deluge doesn't have one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like [qBittorrent](http://qbittorrent.sourceforge.net/). I am not so familiar with torrents but [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/qbittorrent/index.php?title=How_to_use_qBittorrent_as_a_tracker) is something on embeddedtracker.

Comment: It may(?) suit, but I'm running 10.04 and the repo only has v2.2.5-1.. The tracker is only available from v2.5.0 on.. (even 10.10 repos have only v2.4.3-0).. so you're on track (+1), but I'll hang out for another "in the repo" option... (and perhaps use this as a fallback if it is suitable for 10.04)....

Comment: you can use getdeb {http://getdeb.net} or ppa {https://launchpad.net/~hydr0g3n/+archive/ppa} for latest one

Comment: #sagarchalise: I've taken the launchpad PPA route... I had quite a time getting it running .... I gradually isolated the problem to my router, so I phoned my ISP (they provided the router)... and I found out that they were port blocking by default... That may explain a few other problems I've been having!  .. anyhow it was easily resolved and I've got all my ports back :).... and qBitTorrent' embedded tracker works fine... Dhanyavaad

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu comes with `Transmission` as standard Bit-torrent client. You find it in `Applications -> Internet -> Tranmission`

It has a possibility for `private` torrents. `File -> New...` last checkbox

Comment: I wonder if I'm using the right terminology.. I can't seem to find what I'm after... I actually want to be the tracker of my own torrent..  I think(?) the option you have mentioned is to create a .torrent which is assigned to a private tracker... That's good, but I don't see any option to actually **be the tracker** ...  Am I off-track here ? :)

Comment: I never created a torrent myself. But as far as I understand you have to add the tracker URL. If you don't own a tracker server which you could indicate, you might have to add your IP?

Comment: :) ... getting closer... Yes I did need to supply my IP, and it needs  the tracker server... uTorent had an embedded tracker server... that's what I'm after...  a Client/Tracker combo..

Comment: I don't think this is possible with Transmission. At least not out of the box.